# Assign macro to buttons across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

How can I assign this macro to buttons across multiple sheets; ie. irrespective of whether a button's name is "Button 1" or "Button 2"?

```
Public SelectionChange_Enabled As Boolean
Sub Button1_Click()
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Disable Events" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Enable Events"
    SelectionChange_Enabled = False
Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Disable Events"
    SelectionChange_Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Application.Caller` to determine what called a routine.  You could use it like this

To only update the button that was clicked

```
Sub AllButtons_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        If .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Disable Events" Then
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Enable Events"
            SelectionChange_Enabled = False
        Else
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Disable Events"
            SelectionChange_Enabled = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

and assign all buttons to `AllButtons_Click`

To update buttons accross all worksheets (that use this `Sub`)

```
Sub AllButtons_Click2()
    Dim shp As Button
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    SelectionChange_Enabled = Not SelectionChange_Enabled
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each shp In sh.Buttons
            If shp.OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!AllButtons_Click2" Then
                If SelectionChange_Enabled Then
                    shp.Caption = "Disable Events"
                Else
                    shp.Caption = "Enable Events"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. How could I update all buttons' text so that, when I click one button, all other buttons register the same change?

Comment: Hmm... by "all buttons" I suppose I meant all buttons that have `AllButtons_Click` assigned to them :)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! (I just had to swap the button text around).

Comment: I noticed that `SelectionChange_Enabled` starts off as disabled; clicking a button (while the button text says "Disable") enables it. Could you please make `SelectionChange_Enabled` start off as enabled, with the button text saying "Disable" and the first click disabling it?

Comment: The default value of a Public `BOOL`'s is `FALSE`, so `SelectionChange_Enabled` naturally starts out Disabled (false).  I see two options 1) add a `Workbook_Open` that calls your click sub.  This will toggle `SelectionChange_Enabled` to enabled and set your button texts.  2) Change the sense of your flag to `SelectionChange_Disabled` (Disabled = False, = Enabled) and set the default button text in the VBE.  This way no startup action is required.